# Cannot run a parallel grid search in H2O

Tags: parallel-processing, h2o, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to use the new "parallelism" option of H2O's grid search to tune the hyperparameters of a GBM model with a 3-fold cross-validation. However, the search is failing, or rather just stopping, as soon as the first batch of the models is built.

A bit of context: I am submitting this grid search job to an H2O cluster on the remote server on hadoop. I'm creating the cluster with, say, 5 nodes. Here's an example: `hadoop jar /usr/local/h2o/bin28/h2odriver.jar -nodes 5 -mapperXmx 30g -baseport 54364 -disown`. I have a an indicator column for the fold assignment.

With `parallelism = 0`, the grid search is starting with 5 models in parallel (with 2 cv models for each first, and then the 3rd cv model once those are done). As soon as these 5 models complete, the search is just finishing.

The grid search works fine if I run it sequentially with parallelism turned off, but I can't figure out why it won't work with parallelism.

I would appreciate any help with this.
Thank you!

EDIT:
Correction - looks the "parallelism = 1" option isn't working either. The search just stops after one model. This was not an issue with the previous version of H2O - v3.26.03.